# Excel VBA activate objects if checkbox ticked

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, textbox

I have got a piece of code that works which changes a input field from disabled to enabled and changes the colour from gray to white if the corresponsding checkbox is ticked.

Is there a way to loop this or call it for all checkboxes & input fields without having a seperate piece of code for each pair?

The code I have is:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
  tb01.Enabled = True
  tb01.BackColor = vbWhite

Else:   tb01.Enabled = False
        tb01.BackColor = vb3DLight
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
  tb02.Enabled = True
  tb02.BackColor = vbWhite

Else:   tb02.Enabled = False
        tb02.BackColor = vb3DLight
End If
End Sub
```

edit: This code is in a UserForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes are a collection in Excel, you can do something like this:

```
Sub SelectCheckboxes()  
    Dim CB As CheckBox  
    For Each CB In Sheet1  
      If CB.Name <> Sheet1.CheckBoxes("SkipThisCheckbox").Name Then  
        CB.Value = 2
      End If  
    Next CB  
End Sub
```

You change the value to all checkboxes, except the "SkipThisCheckbox" checkbox.

Edit: The idea is that the checkboxes are a collection and I have translated your question as "show me how to select/check checkboxes together and not one by one".

On a form it should be something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cCont As Control
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "Checkbox" Then
       Debug.Print cCont 
       'True or False if checked
       'Write your logic here.
    End If
 Next cCont
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for replying Vityata. I'm not sure I follow. I don't want to change the value of the checkboxes, I want to see if a checkbox is checked and if it is, enable the corresponding textbox. How does your script do that? Also, this is in a UserForm not the sheet.

Comment: Thanks again Vityata, that does make some sense to me. So If I wanted it to enable the corresponding textbox would I require a similar code within the " 'write your logic here " to select them in turn?

Comment: Yes. Something similar. Depending on how your texboxes are named. E.g. if they are like "tb2" and the checkboxes are up to 9, you can come up with logic to read the last character of the checkbox name and to enable the label with the similar last character. If the checkboxes are more than 9, then it would be a little more complicated - you have to read two characters :)

Answer (score 0):

the more versatile approach is a module class one

here follows a possible application to your case, assuming that TextBoxes and CheckBoxes in your UserForm are paired on a "Name" property basis like "CheckBox1"-"TextBox1", "CheckBox2"-"TextBox2", ...

- in the UserForm code pane place the following code

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Dim chkBoxes(1 To 4) As ChkBox_TxtBox_Class 'array of type "ChkBoxClass" which you define in a Class Module

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim nControls As Integer, i As Integer

  nControls = 4 '<== set here the number of CheckBox-TextBox pairs you have in the Form
  For i = 1 To nControls

      Set chkBoxes(i) = New ChkBox_TxtBox_Class 'initialize a new instance of 'ChkBoxClass' class and store it in the array i-th position
      With chkBoxes(i)
          Set .ChkBox = Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i) 'assign the correct CheckBox control to its ChkBox property
          Set .TxtBox = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)  'assign the correct TextBox control to its TxtBox property
          .ChkBox.value = False 'set "unchecked" as checkbox initial value
          .SetTexBox ' call the class method that will have the "paired" textbox adjust its state accordingly to checkbox value
      End With

  Next i

  End Sub
  ```
- add a "Class Module" to your project

  either clicking Insert-> Class Module in the VBA IDE main Ribbon menu

  or right-clicking anywhere in the VBA IDE Project Window and selecting Insert -> Class Module in subsequent sub-menus
- expand the "Class Module" node in the Project Window

  if you don't see the Project Window you can open it by clicking View-> Project Window in the main ribbon menu, or press "Ctrl+R"
- select the new Class you added (it should be some "Class1" or the likes) and change its name to "ChkBox_TxtBox_Class" in the Property Window "Name" textbox

  if you don't see the Property Window you can open it by clicking View-> Property Window in the main ribbon menu or press "F4"
- in the Class Module code pane place the following

  ```
      Option Explicit

      'declare class properties of CheckBox and TextBox type to be "paired" in every instance of this class. the CheckBox one will be associated to events
      Public WithEvents ChkBox As MSForms.CheckBox ' ChkBox is a property of the class of type CheckBox. it's associated to events
      Public TxtBox As MSForms.TextBox ' TxtBox is a property of the class of type TextBox

      ' events associated to ChkBox class property
     Sub ChkBox_Change()
         Call SetTexBox 'call the "method" (i.e. a Sub attached to the class) associated to ChkBox property state change
     End Sub


     Sub SetTexBox()
     'sub that sets the state of the associated TextBox accordingly to the state of the associated CheckBox
     With Me.ChkBox
          If .value Then
              TxtBox.Enabled = True
              TxtBox.BackColor = vbWhite
          Else
              TxtBox.Enabled = False
              TxtBox.BackColor = vb3DLight
          End If
     End With

     End Sub
  ```
- run your routine